# Elm docs - What does "a" mean?

Tags: elm

Elm docs give no example usage, so it's hard to understand what the type specs mean. In several places I've seen "a" used as an argument identifier, like in [Platform.Cmd](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Platform-Cmd):

```
map : (a -> msg) -> Cmd a -> Cmd msg
```

What does this mean? How would I use `Cmd.map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is a *type variable*. Think of it as a **placeholder that can be substituted by any other type**. However, all occurences of `a` in one type signature must be substituted with the same concrete type.

So if `map` has this signature...

```
(a -> msg) -> Cmd a -> Cmd msg
```

...this would be a valid substitution:

```
(Bool -> MyMessage) -> Cmd Bool -> Cmd MyMessage
```

(`msg` is another type variable)

...while this would be an incorrect substitution:

```
(Bool -> MyMessage) -> Cmd MyMessage -> Cmd Bool  -- note the mismatched type variables
```

Having type variables gives a lot of flexibility, because a generic function like `map` can be reused with all kinds of different types.

Answer (score 5):

Here is part of [Elm Guide about reading Types Annotations](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/reading_types.html#primitives-and-lists):

```
> [ "Alice", "Bob" ]
[ "Alice", "Bob" ] : List String

> [ 1.0, 8.6, 42.1 ]
[ 1.0, 8.6, 42.1 ] : List Float

> []
[] : List a
```

> In the first case, we have a List filled with String values. In the
>   second, the List is filled with Float values. In the third case the
>   list is empty, so we do not actually know what kind of values are in
>   the list. So the type List a is saying "I know I have a list, but it
>   could be filled with anything". **The lower-case a is called a type
>   variable, meaning that there are no constraints in our program that
>   pin this down to some specific type. In other words, the type can vary
>   based on how it is used.**

In your case, as a first argument you should pass a function which will take a variable of type from second argument and return value of type msg.

Comment: What do you mean by "take type from second argument"?

Comment: Second argument which you pass to `Cmd.map` is type of `Cmd a` where `a` can be any other type. So this `a type` has to be accepted by function passed as first argument.

Comment: This is all still fuzzy to me. Could you add an usage example?

Answer (score 3):

I think of it like Java generics, the `a` is the generic *raw* type.

E.g., in java, `List <String>` is a `java.util.List` of `String`s - this is a concrete type of List. You can also define methods with signature like `List<A>` where `A` is a raw generic type, where the `A` is passed in by the calling method. [Here is the Java explanation of raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Similarly, in Elm, the `List a` the `a` is a place holder for a generic type.

Comment: `A raw type is the name of a generic class or interface without any type arguments` - wouldn't the raw type be `List` then?

Comment: You're right. I was trying to draw the parallel from Java raw types to substitution concept you explain, 'place holder' in my answer.